# How to jump from .hpp to actual source code (.pas) file?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-tokyo

In C++ Builder, if you <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on an identifier (a VCL class name, for instance), it will take you to the `.hpp` file where that identifier is declared.  But, to see the ACTUAL Pascal code for that class, you need to open Explorer and go hunt down the corresponding PAS file.  That is such a waste of time.

Is there a way to convince the IDE to go to the actual source code (`.pas` file) instead of the `.hpp`?  Or maybe an IDE plug-in?

Comment: I am bound to much older IDEs so it might not work for you but I usually do it by placing breakpoint on line in question and step in [F7] ... on runtime after breakpoint fires up ... If `AnsiString` is involved you might need to step [F7] few times until you hit code you want ... then stop IIRC [CTRL+F2]  while your cursor is clicked in file in question to prevent automatic close on exit...

Comment: @Spektre - I don't mean necessary during debugging. Rather during design. The IDE simply makes finding the PAS source code a time-consuming task. That's unnecessary. They could implement something like Delphi's Ctrl+click -> go to "real" source code. I mean, the IDE already knows the function name and file name.      --------  It is something so BASIC that I think that it MUST already exists but it is not activated in my IDE - hence my question: "how do I activate it?"

Answer (score 1):

If you type the name of the .pas file on a blank line, then put the cursor into it, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will open the file in the IDE.